# Show button "Add to cart" of WooCommerce only to my friends buddypress

Tags: woocommerce, conditional-statements, buddypress

I created a site with buddypress and WooCommerce and everyone can upload products to the store. The idea is that if you're a friend of the author, you can buy the product.

I have customized the file simple.php WooCommerce / single-product / add-to-cart / folder and I've added this code:

```
global $bp;
if (friends_check_friendship( !bp_displayed_user_id(), bp_loggedin_user_id())) { 
    echo ' Add To Cart';
}
elseif (!friends_check_friendship( !bp_displayed_user_id(), bp_loggedin_user_id())) { 
echo 'Only Friends';
}
```

But it does not work. This code only works if you are the administrator, and always have to be a friend of the administrator to display the "Add To Cart" button. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bp_displayed_user_id()`  only works on BuddyPress profile pages.

Assuming the single-product page was created by a specific user, you need the author id.

Try this:

```
if (friends_check_friendship( get_the_author_meta('ID'), bp_loggedin_user_id())) { 
    echo ' Add To Cart';
}
else
    echo 'Only Friends';
```